# How can I force the auxiliary angle method to work on this question?

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan{a}=\frac{x}{y}$, when what is the value of $x\cos{2a}+y\sin{2a}$? I know you can simply draw a trialge and expand the trig identities but the auxiliary method should also work in this case, but Im not sure how to continue. I have so far $R\cos{(2a-\beta)}$ where $R = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\beta = \arctan{\frac{y}{x}}$. How can I simplify further to get the answer of $x$? I am stuck on $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\big{(}(2\arctan{\frac{x}{y}})-\arctan{\frac{y}{x}}\big{)}$$

Comment: a typo maybe ?  the value of  $(-x \cos 2a +y \sin 2a)$ equals $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the relations
$$\cos 2a=\frac{1-\tan^2a}{1+\tan^2 a};\;\sin 2a=\frac{2\tan a}{1+\tan^2 a}$$
set $\tan a=t$
$$x\cos{2a}+y\sin{2a}=\frac{1-t^2 }{t^2+1}x+\frac{2 t }{t^2+1}y$$
$t=\frac{x}{y}$
$$x\cos{2a}+y\sin{2a}=\frac{2 x}{\frac{x^2}{y^2}+1}+\frac{x \left(1-\frac{x^2}{y^2}\right)}{\frac{x^2}{y^2}+1}=\frac{3 x y^2-x^3}{x^2+y^2}$$

Comment: I see. I needed t-formulae in this case. I never seem to know when to use t-formulae except in Weirstrasse substitution and when its explicitly stated to use